# Is there a common notation for describing this operation $coNP\; ? \; NP = DP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, notation

While working with complexity classes, I've come along the definition of $DP$ (or $D^p$):
$$DP = \{L_1 \cap L_2 \mid L_1 \in NP \text{ and } L_2 \in coNP\}$$

I am interested in a different (and much shorter form) of describing this exact operation on class-level, rather than language-level
$$coNP\; ? \; NP = DP$$

Since this is different than just cutting both classes, I was wondering what symbol is commonly used for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the theory of "[abstract families of languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages)" one uses the notation $\mathcal K \land \mathcal L$ to denote the pairwise intersection of languages in $\mathcal K$ and $\mathcal L$, thus $\{\;K\cap L\mid K\in\mathcal K \text{ and } L\in\mathcal L\;\}$.

That theory is probably half a century old with work of Greibach, Ginsberg and others. A rather recent occurrence of this notation is Semilinearity of Families of Languages, by Ibarra and McQuillan, [arXiv:2212.01301](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.01301). See top of page 5.

This agrees with the suggestion you propose in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any standard notation to represent this operation.  You could invent your own notation, but make sure you define it in a self-contained way, so that readers understand what you mean by it.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I thought about using $\land$ since it pinpoints to the fact that both languages need to be included in the respective class, but I'm afraid to overload the symbol.